# In if-elif-else, the if statement is TRUE yet the else statement is getting executed

Tags: python, if-statement

```
string = "aabbcc"
count = 3
while True:
    if string[0] == 'a':
        string = string[2:]
    elif string[-1] == 'b':
        string = string[:2]
    else:
        count += 1
        break
print(string)
print(count)
```

The output for the program is 'bbcc' and 4. But I don't understand why the else statement is running when the IF statement is true. Please help.

Comment: Because it is a loop. `white True:` executes once to strip out the aa, then a second time it goes through the else.

Comment: First time into the loop string == 'aabbcc' therefore *if string[0] == 'a'* is True. Second pass and string == 'bbcc' therefore *if string[0] == 'a'* is False. What were you expecting?

Comment: if you put a *break* in your `if`, `elif` then you will understand

Comment: See [Effective Debugging Techniques in Python](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/effective-debugging-techniques-in-python-6a2a7eafdc7c).

Comment: @DarkKnight oh I didn't know that the loop would continue if the value of string got changed within the loop. Thank you

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it? The loop condition doesn't depend in the value of `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using while loop remember.

```
string = "aabbcc"
count = 3
while True:
    if string[0] == 'a': 
        string = string[2:]
        # here the value of string is assigned as bbcc
    elif string[-1] == 'b':
        string = string[:2]
    else:
        count += 1
        break
print(string)
print(count)
```

*After the vaiable string is assigned by bbcc, the loop runs again and this time string[0] != "a" and is equal to "b". Therefore the statement in else is executed and the count becomes 4 and the loop breaks because of the break statement*

> There is no bug in the code And the code is running fine as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

The value of string gets replaced, then the loop continues. The second iteration, the string doesn't start with "a" anymore. It also doesn't end with "b". So you get 3+1 and "bbcc".

Comment: didn't know that would happen. thank you